# Filling table by yield return

Tags: c#, datatable, yield-return

I  started adventure with C# a month ago. Can You please help me with problem below?
How to insert the results obtained by Yield return and insert them into table correctly? As far as result I get the table filled by the same, last generated value (10+5=15). What I need is to have series of results generated step by step by `yield return` function.

```
public class Obliczenia
{
   // double P1, P2, V, S, R, P1a, Sa, Va;
   public IEnumerable<double> Wyniki
   {
       get
       {
           for (double Rf = 0; Rf <= 10; Rf += 1)
           {
               yield return Rf + 5; // finally here will be more complicated equation
           }
       }
   }
}


string[] tablica1 = new string[100];
Obliczenia o = new Obliczenia();

foreach (double wynik in o.Wyniki)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
   {
       tablica1[i] = wynik.ToString();  // I think, something wrong is here.
   }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting array elements in each iteration. You should update `i` to a new value in every iteration.

Comment: Can You/anyone please tell me how to do it in that case?

Comment: @Kamran Finally I have found how to insert results to List : ```List<double> Lista = new List<double>();

            Obliczenia o = new Obliczenia();
            
            foreach (double wynik in o.Wyniki)
            {
                Lista.Add(wynik);

            } ```    However, I do not have idea how to do it with table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
string[] tablica1 = new string[100];
Obliczenia o = new Obliczenia();

var k = 0;

foreach (double wynik in o.Wyniki)
{                
    tablica1[k] = wynik.ToString();
    k++;                               
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Kamran.